# Sharepoint integration for entity kbarticle on CRM 2016

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We have had a CRM 2015 OnPremise which used standard Sharepoint integration for several entities, among others the entity "kbarticle". Then we upgraded to CRM 2016. Afterwards, we have problems with the document upload for entity kbarticle. If I click on "Documents" on the left menu of a kbarticle record now, the CRM tries to generate a sharepoint folder - but with the wrong URL:

I would expect a new folder for the record at `"mysharepoint/sites/mysite/kbarticle/MyRecordName_[GUID]"`

But the CRM takes: `"mysharepoint/sites/mysite/kbarticle"`

As you can see the CRM does not try to generate a subfolder for the record, but takes the parent folder only. Furthermore when I click "Ok", the error message `"Both absoluteurl and relativeurl cannot be null"` appears.

This issue does only occur for entity kbarticle and only on CRM 2016. I checked the sharepoint integration settings. All seems to be ok.

I know that the entity kbarticle is obsolete in CRM 2016, but does anybody know if the issue can be solved?